Python type checker doesn't recognise a Pydantic dynamic model as a type
Example code:
import pydantic

DYNAMIC_KEYS = ["I", "don't", "know", "these", "at", "compile", "time"]

MyClass = pydantic.create_model("MyClass", **{key: (int, 0) for key in DYNAMIC_KEYS})


def f(thing: MyClass) -> None:
    print(thing.I)
    print(thing.time)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    external_data = {"these": 3, "time": 42}
    my_thing = MyClass(**external_data)
    f(my_thing)

This code prints 0 and 42 as expected, but my problems is with the type-checker (currently I use Pyright that comes bundled with VS Code). If I hover over MyClass in the line def f(thing: MyClass) -> None:, the type checker complains:
Variable not allowed in type expression Pylance (reportInvalidTypeForm)

So it seems to think that MyClass is a variable, not a type. Is there a way to make the type checker (specifically Pyright) to realise that MyClass is a type and not a variable?
I've tried the following but no joy:
from typing import Type, cast

import pydantic

DYNAMIC_KEYS = ["I", "don't", "know", "these", "at", "compile", "time"]

MyClass = cast(Type, MyClass)

assert isinstance(MyClass, Type)

assert isinstance(MyClass, type)



Possible duplicates: Dynamic type hinting for dynamically created classes, How to typehint dynamic class instantiation like pydantic and dataclass?. TLDR: It's not possible. The answer about @dataclass_transform() of the last linked question doesn't apply in your case, since you don't know the fields at type-checking time.
